# Issue with PDFMod since upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pdf

For years I had been using `PDFMod` to easily move, rotate, delete, and add pages to a PDF.  I always thought it was a very useful little package.

Unfortunately, since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 some six months ago I can only open about half the documents with it.  The error message says `Error Loading Document` followed by the full name of the file.

Anyone encountered the same issue?  Has anyone been able to fix this?  Is there an alternative to PDFMod that may work better/more consistently.

In case anyone is familiar, and for debugging purposes, here is the output when I ran `pdfmod` from the command line with a file that produces the error:

```
pdfmod Carretero_Discovery_2016_Proposal_02-REFERENCES.pdf 
[1 Debug 15:17:15.984] Starting PdfMod 0.9.1
[1 Debug 15:17:15.992] Initializing i18n catalog from /usr/share/locale/
[1 Debug 15:17:16.098] Loaded custom AccelMap from /home/username/.config/pdfmod/gtk_accel_map
[1 Debug 15:17:16.113] Cache directory set to /home/username/.cache/pdfmod
[1 Debug 15:17:16.622] Loaded PROBLEM-FILE.pdf
[3 Warn  15:17:16.779] Caught an exception - PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReaderException: Cannot handle iref streams. The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6. (in `PdfSharp')
  at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.Parser.ReadXRefTableAndTrailer (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfReferenceTable xrefTable) <0x406c5410 + 0x002cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.Parser.ReadTrailer () <0x406c3e00 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, System.String password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfPasswordProvider passwordProvider) <0x406c17a0 + 0x002b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open (System.String path, System.String password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfPasswordProvider provider) <0x406c15c0 + 0x00077> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open (System.String path, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfPasswordProvider provider) <0x406c1580 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfMod.Pdf.Document.Load (System.String uri, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfPasswordProvider passwordProvider, Boolean isAlreadyTmp) <0x406b9000 + 0x00277> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at PdfMod.Gui.Client+<LoadPath>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <0x406b8830 + 0x001bf> in <filename unknown>:0 
[3 Error 15:17:16.783] Error Loading Document - There was an error loading /home/username/PROBLEM-FILE.pdf
```

Comment: Does the error appear for those documents that worked before? Or, rather, for new ones? I'm asking because the output says that the app didn't have some feature implemented, and with regard to your answer it's either an irrelevant bug triggering a wrong description *(in case you could open those documents before)*, or it's a known limitation of the app that devs didn't yet overcome.

Comment: It is not working on documents generated the same way.  The one mentioned above is a document generated from LaTeX.

Comment: @JuanAntonio it's perfectly possible that LaTeX upon upgrade started using the "iref streams" feature. I'd recommend to test PDFMod on older documents rather than new ones.

Comment: @Hi-Angel no doubt, based on the errors listed in the post, that there is something in the new PDF files that PDFMod cannot handle.  Unfortunately, it does not change the fact that PDFMod is no longer compatible/useful.

Comment: @DKBose I tried pdfshuffler and it works.  I will transition to that one.  Incidentally, many years back I started using that one instead of PDFMod but, at the time, found it cluncky.  I just tried it and it seems quite improved from the version I remember.  I am glad there is an option though.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue with PdfMod on Ubuntu 16.04. After many futile attempts, I decided to switch to [PdfShuffler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) which does the job the same way.

Comment: Yes, I am now using PdfShuffler as suggested by @DKBose in a comment.  However, I had a file the other day that would make PdfShuffler consistently crash yet, strangely enough, PdfMod worked.  Between the two I have a working solution but would like to have one.  Unfortunately, cannot pick any answer yet as these are 'workarounds' and not really solutions to the PdfMod problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use 1.50 or later version of PDFMod, [accordingly to their forum](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9612#p9612) it's the version where  iref streams were finally handled.

Comment: According to Ubustu Software Centre, only version 0.9.1-8 of PDFMod is available.  Moreover, according to PDFMod's official website (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/PdfMod), that is the latest version.  It seems as though the forum you are referring to may not exactly deal with PDFMod.  If seems to be talking about PDFSharp which is not the same (nor it is available through the Ubuntu Software Centre).

Comment: @JuanAntonio hmm it's interesting indeed. The backtrace from PDFMod mentiones PDFSharp, that's why I confused. Then PDFMod probably uses PDFSharp library, something like that. I'd ask then PDFMod developers to update their app to the latest PDFSharp.

Comment: will do but they no longer seem to be active (last update was March 3, 2011).  At this point it seems as though switching to PDFShuffle may be the safest option.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find pdfshuffler in Ubuntu. But under Ubuntu 2022,

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

solves the problem perfectly, in that `pdfarranger` looks rather like `pdfmod` except that it works on my files.

By the way, I found this solution by typing

```
 apt search shuffler
```

at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for complete editing of a PDF, "Libre Office Draw" can easily do it and a master piece software which is free for Linux for basic use is " "Master PDF Editor 4"